# Connect heroku log drain to logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, heroku, logstash

I created an elasticsearch cluster on [Elastic Cloud](https://www.elastic.co/cloud) and am trying to send logs to it from Heroku. So far I am not receiving data.

I have the following questions:

1. What URL should I use for the log drain when running heroku drains:add? When I access Kibana my URL is https://my_id.us-east-1.aws.found.io:9243. Should I use that? Or remove the port?
2. How should I set up my Logstash config? Right now I have it set up using [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jblomo/2c7cca06a0a6c351f3c6) on GitHub.

Thanks for any help in getting this going.

Answer (score 2):

> What URL should I use for the log drain when running heroku

It should be the URL of the instance that runs Logstash. The URL should include the port Logstash is listening to.

For example, if you're using `https://my_id.us-east-1.aws.found.io` as the instance address, and using the gist you've mentioned as your logstash config, the URL should be:

```
https://my_id.us-east-1.aws.found.io:1514
```

> How should I set up my Logstash config?

Well, it depends. The gist you've mentioned may be a good start. But it's pretty dated. So if it doesn't work, here are some things to consider:

- according to "[HTTPS drains](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-drains#https-drains)" section from "Log Drains" page of Heroku's official documentation, the logs heroku is sending are *syslog formatted*:

  > With HTTPS drains, Logplex buffers log messages and submits batches of messages to an HTTPS endpoint via a POST request. The POST body contains syslog formatted messages ...
- in the "Processing Syslog Messages" section from "Logstash Configuration Examples" page of ElasticSearch's official documentation, there's a sample of Logstash config that will parse syslog-formatted messages.

  Here's that example in full:

  ```
  filter {
    if [type] == "syslog" {
      grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
        add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
        add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
      }
      date {
        match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
      }
    }
  }

  output {
    elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
  }
  ```

  Note: in this config you need to change `localhost:9200` to the address of your Elasticsearch cluster on Elastic Cloud.

---

Additionally, here's a [sample](https://github.com/jesperfj/heroku-log-drain-sample/blob/master/process_logs.go) application code, written in [[image]go](/questions/tagged/go). It does not involve Logstash. Instead, it does custom processing of the log data.